# I just followed the step by step process on google cloud function tutorial , anyone know how to fix this? or the cause of the problem?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I only followed the step by step tutorial on google firebase
this is the link:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?authuser=0

and then I get these on cmd

```
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: /user_code/index.js:9
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
                                                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at getUserFunction (/var/tmp/worker/worker.js:439:24)


Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        addMessage
```

> These are the codes on the tutorial.

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into the
// Realtime Database under the path /messages/:pushId/original
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
// Grab the text parameter.
const original = req.query.text;
  // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.`enter code here`
  const snapshot = await admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: 
original});
 // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the 
Firebase console.
  res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref.toString());
});
```

Comment: Please read the [help] for details about asking a good question including information about writing good titles.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you posted compared to the code in the example, I think the problem is:

Your code:

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
```

example code:

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
```

Notice that in your code there is no "space" character after `async`.  Async is a qualifier of a function that flags the function as asynchronous.  See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for details of async.

The omission of the space changes the semantics.  If I had to guess, the runtime would now be looking for a function that is *called* `async`.  Please change your code to include a space.

Comment: I already removed the space but now it gives me this
`exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async(req,res) => {`

---
now the arrow ^ is pointing on the "("  after async

Comment: Can you edit/update your whole question so that it reflects the current state of the puzzle?